# iPython not responding while program is running. Will respond when program quits

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm fairly new to programming, so please bear with me.
I have som difficulty explaining my problem, so i posted som pictures to help. This is a general problem i'm having

I made an interactive program that prompts the user for some data. The user can do some operations on the data, including visualizing it. I made a plot function, using matplotlib.pyplot.

When the user chooses to visualize the data an iPython window pop's up, but is showing 'not responding'. When the user quits the program, the plot will appear.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
timeline = np.arange(5)

while True:
    choice = int(input("Please choose a number, 0 or 1: "))
    if choice == 1:
        plt.plot(timeline, data)
    if choice == 0:
        break
```

This is what happens when i type 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/haA8D.jpg

This is what happens when i type 0: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HZlg.jpg

Comment: Please try and reduce your problem to a short program that shows the same problem. Obviously, such a program does not need to read data, and simply plot a line. It doesn't need to present 6 choices as input, but just a simple input prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
timeline = np.arange(5)

while True:
    choice = int(input("Please choose a number, 0 or 1: "))
    if choice == 1:
        plt.plot(timeline, data)
        plt.pause(0.001)
        plt.draw()
    if choice == 0:
        break
```

The plt.pause and plt.draw tell matplotlib to directly draw the figure. I also included plt.ion which is always helpful but not necessary in this case.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained *why* your code works.